# Why my native android app is marked as not compatible with some chinese tablet?

Tags: android-ndk, google-play, android, android-compatibility

I've a native app compiled for armeabi and armeabi-v7a
Some users reported me that the Android Market says that my app is not compatible with their device, and I really don't understand why it isn't.

In the AndroidManifest.xml I've:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

aapt dump badging output:

```
package: name='XXXXXXXXXXX' versionCode='12' versionName='0.2.5.1'
sdkVersion:'5'
targetSdkVersion:'15'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
application-label:'XXXXXX'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='XXXXXX' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.location.network'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
other-activities
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
native-code: 'armeabi' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

At this moment I've this two tablet that got from Android market "This app isn't compatible": flytouch 4 and Intreeo MID-WL7

For Intreeo MID-WL7 I've also this Quick system info pro report:

```
Hardware    wmt
Release 2.2
SDK 8
Build   generic-eng 2.2 Froyo v1.2.0-20110920.163014

Processor : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS : 797.97
Features : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part : 0x926
CPU revision : 5
Hardware : WMT
```

Fly touch system report:

```
Device: disco10
Modello: DISCO10
Board: unknown
Prodotto: DISCO10
Brand: generic
Produttore: unknown
CPU+ABI: armeabi
Bootloader: unknown
Radio: unknown
Hardware: imapx200
Release: 2.2
SDK: 8
Tipo: user
Build: FRF85B
Locale: it_IT

Linux version 2.6.32.9 (zjd@dtlinuxserver) (gcc version 4.4.0 (GCC) ) #1 Wed Jun 1 08:59:52 CST 2011
```

Comment: do you know if it is actually able to run on the hardware, and is just limited by the market?

Comment: Yes, I sent him the .apk and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the tablets in question likely do not have a phone state to be read since they are not phones.  Pretty sure I read that if a required permission is unavailable then the app will be blocked.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I've added the aapt dump badging output and there is nothing related to phone in uses-feature. If the apk needs the phone "feature" I think the aapt dump badging output should show it, or am I wrong?